# c++ templates argument based compilation

Tags: c++, templates

I want to write a template function which calls a different method based on type of template argument. Ex-

```
template<typename T>
void GetData(T& data)
{
   if(T is int)
      Call_Int_Method(data);
   else if(T is double)
      Call_Double_Method(data);   // This call will not compile if data is int
   ...
}
```

Basically, GetData should only be calling one method based on type of T. Other calls should not exist. Is it possible somehow?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/

Comment: If you are only looking at int and double, you want a function `void GetData(int&);` and `void GetData(double&);` Otherwise see template specialisation.

Comment: @deviantfan not needed, this is specialisation of a template, if templates are needed at all.

Comment: You can use the [`typeid()` operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) to check this. But I doubt that's really a good idea.

Comment: @AlecTeal It is not needed, but it can be a helpful tool here. I mean, you don't want to over engineer things, and overloading is the minimum tool to get the job done, but it can be much less flexible.

Answer (score 8):

Provide some overloads, either of `GetData` if you need the whole function to have specific behaviour for `int` or `double`:

```
void GetData(int& data)
{
  Call_Int_Method(data);
}

void GetData(double& data)
{
  Call_Double_Method(data);
}
```

or the `Call_X_Methods` if only a portion of the function's logic is to be specialized:

```
template<typename T>
void DoTypeSpecificStuff(T& data) { /* stuff */ }

void DoTypeSpecificStuff(int& data) { .... }

void DoTypeSpecificStuff(double& data) { .... }

template<typename T>
void GetData(T& data)
{
   DoTypeSpecificStuff(data);

   // do other stuff
   ....
}
```

Note that overload resolution will favour non-templates over function templates when the types match, so you can be sure the right function will be called for these two types.

Comment: Or use template specialization, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Overloads might be the preferred solution here, let alone because they put a lower maintenance burden on you:

```
void GetData(int& data)
{
   Call_Int_Method(data);
}

void GetData(double& data)
{
   Call_Double_Method(data);   // This call will not compile if data is int
}
```

Or, depending on the innards of `Call_(int|double)_Method`, maybe you can overload *them*:

```
template <typename T>
void GetData (T &data) {
    CallMethod (data);
}

void CallMethod (int &) {}
void CallMethod (double &) {}
```

But again, possibly is is better maintainable if you restrict the type of `T`, using overloading again:

```
void GetData (int &data) { CallMethod (data); }
void GetData (double &data) { CallMethod (data); }
```

You can also restrict the instantiable types in templates with type traits, but that might be less maintainable.

But maybe your situation is different, and you have a template that works for all types, except some cherry-picked ones:

```
// general template
template <typename T>
void GetData (T &data) {...}

// function, technically not an overload
void GetData (std::string &data) {....}

// this is an overload of the GetData(std::string&)-function:
void GetData (std::map<int,int> &) {....}
```

There is plenty to choose from and no single correct answer. Possibly giving you some rules of thumbs for maintainable code is best:

### Incomplet and incorrekt list of Real Advices (ɔ):

- **Templates can be nice if used sanely**
- **Templates can be horror is used insanely**
- Prefer plain overloads
- Reconsider your problem from time to time and try to judge if you then-chosen solution is *still* what makes most sense. I.e., keep flexible and learn refactoring.
- **Always** strive for readability.

A good readability check is to let your code rest for some days and review it again to see if you still know what you have done. If everything's okay, repeat this test at larger time intervals.

Answer (score 1):

Since no one is putting this here yet, I thought I'd give another option (that may be overkill, simple specialization/overloading is much more readable).

You can use SFINAE (substution failure is not an error) in C++11 (or with boost (or with your own special classes)) if what you are looking to do is select types that meet a certain criteria. While your example is if `T` is an `int` or `T` is a `double`, what if I want to make it more general than that? I want to select if `T` is ANY integral type, and if `T` is ANY floating point type?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value,T>::type foo(T val)
{
   std::cout << "floating function" << std::endl;
   return val;
}

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value,T>::type foo(T val)
{
   std::cout << "integral function" << std::endl;
   return val;
}


int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
  foo(2.0);//T==double, floating point function
  foo(2);///T==int, integral function
  foo(2.0f);//T==float, floating point function
  //foo<std::string>(); throws no matching function for call to foo()
}
```

What is happening here? well std::enable_if is a template  who ONLY has a member `type` iff `val==true`. This makes it so that `std::enable_if<false,T>::type` is an invalid statement. The compiler doesn't automatically throw this as an error. Instead, it looks for other things that it can do.

`std::is_floating_point` and `std::is_integral` simply return the trait values of that type.

Honestly, I like this a little better than simple specialization because it is more easily expandable: you've now allready written your function for `unit8_t`, `long double`, `float`, ect. You can still do specialization on top of this, if any of those need to be different. And compared to overloading, you can more easily explicitly select which function you're talking about (if you want to get the function pointer, `&foo<int>` is tons easier and more readable than `(int(*)(int))&foo`). Like all template methods, it is a compiler time operation, so it shouldn't negatively effect your run-time at all.

The downside? Well, the function declaration is now 99 characters long...

Comment: Overkill, but there is good info here! Upvote! (I support good info in answers! Even if overloading is the answer to the question :) )